# r - scatterplot summary stat (e.g. sum or mean) for each point instead of individual data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am looking for a way to summarize data within a `ggplot` call, not before. I could pre-aggregate the data and then plot it, but I know there is a way to do it within a `ggplot` call. I'm just unsure how.

---

In this example, I want to get a mean for each (x,y) combo, and map it onto the `colour` `aes`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = rep(c(1,2,4,1,5),10), 
             y = rep(c(1,2,3,1,5),10),
             col = sample(c(1:100), 50))

df_summar <- df %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>% 
  summarise(col_mean = mean(col))

ggplot(df_summar, aes(x=x, y=y, col=col_mean)) +
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

---

I think there must be a better way to avoid the pre-ggplot step (yes, I could also have piped `dplyr` transformations into the `ggplot`, but the mechanics would be the same).

For instance, `geom_count()` counts the instances and plots them onto `size` `aes`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_count()
```

I want the same, but `mean` instead of `count`, and `col` instead of `size`

---

I'm guessing I need `stat_summary()` or a `stat()` call (a replacement for ..xxx.. notation), but I can't get it to give me what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need `stat_summary_2d`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = col)) +
  stat_summary_2d(aes(col = ..value..), fun = 'mean', geom = 'point', size = 5)
```

(Or `calc(value)`, if you use the ggplot dev version, or read this in the future.)

You can pass any arbitrary function to `fun`.

While `stat_summary` seems like it would be useful, it is not in this case. It is specialized in the common transformation for plotting, summarizing a range of `y` values, *grouped by x*, into a set of summary statistics that are plotted as `y`(, `ymin` and `ymax`). You want to group by both x and y, so 2d it is.

Note that this uses binning however, so to get the points to accurately line up, you need to increase bin size (e.g. to `1e3`). Unfortunately, there is no non-binning 2d summary stat.

[image]

Comment: Interesting! It works, but I have questions: do we just randomly make up variable `z`? It is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Looks like moving forward one would be able to replace the `..value..` notation with `stat(value)` notation

Comment: `z` is an accepted aesthetic of `stat_summary_2d`. All accepted aesthetics are listed on the help page.

Comment: @Taraas, indeed, but not yet in the current CRAN version.